# spring boot and call stored procedure annotations or entityManger?

Tags: spring-boot, stored-procedures, java-8, jpa-2.1

could someone help me with this, in telling me what is the correct way to call a stored procedure ?

```
1. I've seen annotations to call a procedure like : 
   @Procedure: In this case I have seen that they create the procedure in the entity,
   but I think it is not most optimal.
   @Query: I have been able to call my procedure with this option, but when I would like a
   parameter to be     null, I don't know how to do it since there is
   not much information. 
2. I've been using entityManager and I've been able to make a parameter null, but I don't know if it's 
   the best way to call a procedure with entityManager
```

Another thing, is it good to create a procedure that validates data? or it is not necessary, either in a real case or only valid on the backend side

Answer (score 0):

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries is the better option to call Stored procedures